# Queue builds while agents are offline

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out if builds/deploys are being queued if all agents are offline. Had a situation where nothing was processed and when agents came online, nothing was processed too ci/cd pipelines. This meant we had to either manually trigger a new build or something that triggered a build. 
So my question is if I missed something in devops or if this is by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out if builds/deploys are being queued if all
> agents are offline.

Yes, if the agents of specified pool in build are offline, you will see the below message in the log. And also these build will all be **queued** in order once the available agent online again.

[image]

The order of these builds are executed in the order of the original queues.

In addition, for release which be triggered by build, it will run until the relevant build finish. If the build does not finish running, the relevant release will not be queued.

These is the default design in Azure Devops. According to your description, you'd better check whether the agent which specified in build is same with the agent which you let it online again.

Comment: Thank. I just specify a pool for the build and the pool contains multiple agents. I'll check the logs to see what I can find.

Comment: Hi, how the things going. How about your agent pool?

Comment: Works just as you described. Just had some builds waiting and started as soon as the agent went online. Thanks